# Declaring large array in C++ header

Tags: c++, c, arrays

It's been ages since I last worked with C++.

Situation: I have a large array that needs to be available in different `.cpp` files. It is immutable, so I thought I better put a `const char array[] = …` in the header file. But now the array appears several times   in the compiled binary, as far as I can see.

What is the proper way to declare large constant arrays in a header, so they won't be compiled into every source object?

Comment: There are many duplicates here on SO. If you're too lazy to look for them the solution is to *declare* it in the header file and *define* it in a single source file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you define an array in a header file (whether or not you initialise it), you will get lots of copies.

You want to declare it in the header:

```
extern const char array[];
```

and define it like this in your `.c` / `.cpp` file:

```
const char array[] = ... ;
```

Comment: @Enigma, not it should not be made `static`. In `C`, static globals are not visible to other `.c` files, i.e. the linker will not match one `.c` files the included `extern` from the `.h` file with the definition in the `.c` file that actually has the array in.

Comment: My fault: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1sb61xd.aspx: "By default, an object or variable that is defined outside all blocks has static duration and external linkage."

Comment: Defining a const without initializing it is an error.  The important point here is that `const` objects (unlike other objects) implicitly have internal linkage.

Answer (score -2):

Use the header guard in header file. So it prevent from multiple declaration.
eg.

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
const char array[] = …
.
.
#endif //HEADER_H
```

Comment: Header guards only protects against multiple inclusion in the same translation unit, not against inclusion in multiple translation units.

Comment: This is incorrect. As the header is included by each `.c` / `.cpp` file, with or without the guard, you will get a copy of the array compiled with each `.c` / `.cpp` file.